# Computation of a certain integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $\alpha>0, t \in R$.

Compute the integral

$\int_0^1(-1)^xx^{-\alpha-it}dx.$

Comment: That $(-1)^x$ seems like it might be difficult to deal with. I'm not certain I even know what theat means.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{0}^{1} a^{x} \, x^{-p} \, dx.
\end{align}
Let $\ln(a) \, x = t$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} e^{x \ln(a)} \, x^{-p} \, dx = \ln^{p-1}(a) \,  \int_{0}^{\ln(a)} e^{t} \, t^{-p} \, dt \\
&= (\ln a)^{p-1} \, \left[ - t^{1-p} \, E_{p}(-t) \right]_{0}^{\ln a} \\
&= - E_{p}(- \ln a). 
\end{align}
where $E_{n}(x)$ is the Exponential integral.

For the case of $a = -1$, $p = \alpha + i t$ then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} (-1)^{x} \, x^{-\alpha - i t} \, dx = - E_{\alpha + i t}(- \pi i)
\end{align}

Comment: @ Leucippus   Is there  $0<\alpha <1$ and $ t \in R$  such that $\int_0^1(-1)^xx^{-\alpha-it}dx \neq  0$?

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia nearly all values of $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $t$ satisfy the desired condition.